# Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.profiler"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I just executed app, then I got this errors. I searched about it for a while but couldn’t find clue. How can we make it work?
Anything about this issue is welcome.

## Delopment Info

- Unity 2019.2.11
- Gradle:3.5.3
- API level 28 (Android Pie)

## Device Info

- Android PIXEL3

> E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.profiler"
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
>   E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.gralloc.enable_ahardware_buffer"
>   E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.graphics.memory"
>   W/.resolutionTes: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;->(Ljava/lang/Class;I)V (light greylist, reflection)
>   I/Unity: SystemInfo CPU = ARMv7 VFPv3 NEON, Cores = 8, Memory = 3546mb
>   I/Unity: SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 4 big (mask: 0xf0), 4 little (mask: 0xf)
>   I/Unity: ApplicationInfo com.bagelcode.resolutionTest version 1.0 build 15c7ebaf-9e3b-4e56-8a3e-a8f296eb6bad
>   I/Unity: Built from '2019.2/staging' branch, Version '2019.2.11f1 (5f859a4cfee5)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'mono', CPU 'armeabi-v7a', Stripping 'Disabled'
>   E/SchedPolicy: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple Answer

probably, **before** your error log

`E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.profiler"`

you can see a related warning, something like this:

`type=1400 audit(xxx): avc: denied { read } for name=xxx scontext=xxx tcontext=xxx tclass=xxx permissive=0`

if existed, above warning is the root cause of previous error `Access denied finding property`

### Detailed Explanation

please refer another post's **detailed** answer

[android studio - Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.log.tel_dbg" - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59533551/access-denied-finding-property-persist-vendor-log-tel-dbg/63259127#63259127)

Comment: I don't see a correlation between the name string `vendor.debug.egl.profiler` and anything in your previous "related" warning.  I get a ton of `avc` messages from android devices, I had actually filtered out `-message: avc` prior to reading this answer.  How would I find which avc message might be causing this one access denied that may be causing me grief?  Note: my name string is, of course, different in this case but I am using android and I am seeing libc messages related to the original question.